# cannot create schema using psycopg2

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2

I just started using psycopg2. I am trying to create a schema using Pyscopg2. it seems to execute the schema creation fine BUT i cannot see that the schema is actually created (using PyCharm nor DBeaver) .

```
 #!/usr/bin/python2.4

import psycopg2
from psycopg2.extensions import AsIs

try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='test' user='test' host='localhost' password='test'")
except:
    print("I am unable to connect to the database")

cur = conn.cursor()

try:
    cur.execute('CREATE SCHEMA foo AUTHORIZATION test;')
except:
    print("I am unable to create the schema")
```

what am i doing wrong ? i tried without authorization and got the same result

Comment: What is the error message? Perhaps connect with `psql` and run the statement interactively to find out.

Comment: I never used psycopg2, but might a commit be necessary or does it automatically commits?

Comment: OMG , this is embarrassing but yes, I am missing a `commit` thanks !

Comment: @SimonSchiff. It can if you use the `autocommit` property or use the connection in a context manager(`with conn...`). See here [transactions](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#transactions-control)